# How to add push notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have followed the steps in [this](https://medium.com/@f1lt3r/setting-up-amazon-sns-apache-cordova-for-push-notifications-28510106ae4b) tutorial and have managed to send notifications to my Cordova app.

When I tried to replicate the steps using the production certificate instead, it did not work, so I have two questions:

1) What would I need to do differently in order for it to work?

2) Could I use the development certificate on production? Any restrictions?

Comment: I have never worked with Cordova so I wouldn't know but [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925548/unable-to-add-push-notifications-entitlement-to-ios-production-with-cordova-plug)?

Comment: is there any error messages ?? you cannot use development certificate on production

Comment: The message I get on AWS SNS: `Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EndpointDisabled; Request ID: some-id)`

Answer (score 1):

Build your app using an Ad Hoc provisioning profile in order to test push in a production environment. An app build using an App Store or Ad Hoc profile will use APNS production, while an app build using a Development profile will use the sandbox APNS.

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? Should I use a production or development certificate? I'm very new to both Cordova and Apple development. Thank you!

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK You should use an "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" alongside an app build using an Ad Hoc provisioning profile to test push in production (App Store provisioning profiles are only used when uploading binary to App Store).

Comment: I will try and post the details. Thank you!

Comment: I have tried as you suggested but unless I'm missing something, I got the same error as before: `Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EndpointDisabled; Request ID: some-id)`

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Sorry, I'm not very familiar with AWS services. This post seems to be related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374411/getting-endpointdisabled-from-amazon-sns

Answer (score 1):

development certificate can't use to production , it will invalid. Distinguish development or production is use debug or release model .

[Xcode] --> [product] --> [scheme] --> [edit scheme]

eg:

[image]

Confirmation switch has been opened in developer websit or xcode .

eg:

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instant choosing Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox).you may choose it
apple push notification service ssl (sandbox & production).It will make single pem file for both production and sendbox

if you are using third party for push upload it and test.If you are not then set your app environment production in your server side code and it will work!

Comment: I have tried using the Apple Notification Service SSL and it doesn't work.